# iOS builds on debug but on release mode returns "No such module ..."

Tags: ios, flutter, compilation, release

I'm building on Release mode and I get:

```
    Swift Compiler Error
    No such module 'geofencing'
```

What i've already done:

```
    Flutter clean
    Flutter build ios
```

in /ios:

```
    pod deintegrate
    pod cache clean --all
    rm -r Flutter/Flutter.framework
    rm Podfile.lock
    pod install
```

Clean with xcode aswell, my framework search path is *$(SRCROOT)*
as recursive

This is kinda frustrating :(

PS. The app does compile in Debug and builds the archive